# finder search not issuse

Tags: finder, spotlight

I have enabled showing hidden files in Finder and I can see them when viewing containing folder. However, when I search for such files they do not show in the search results.

Specifically I was searching for `.bash_profile`, which I have created and edited before and I know exists in the file system' But it is not appearing in the results in Finder. I enabled including System Files in Finder but that did not help.

What other changes do I need to do in my system to enable finding these files?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the "File visibility" attribute.  Like this:
[image: File visibility]

The somewhat odd thing is that under "Other..." it is listed as "File invisible" even though it then becomes "File visibility" in the search window.  (macOS 14.1)

Depending on where the file is located you may also need "System files" "Are included".